# I'm trying to save the top three highscores to a txt file on seperate lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's what I have so far.

```
from os import path
dirt = path.dirname(__file__)
#########################################################
def save(hs):
    f = open(path.join(dirt, "testscores.txt"), "w")
    for i in range(3):
        f.write(str(hs[i]))
        if i != len(hs):
            f.write("\n")
    f.close()
def load():
    global hs
    f = open(path.join(dirt, "testscores.txt"), "r")
    hs = f.read().splitlines()
    f.close()
#########################################################
try:
    load()
except:
    hs = [5000, 2000, 300]
hst = int(input("score?"))
hs.append(hst)
print(hs)
hs.sort(key = int, reverse = True)
hs = hs[:3]
save(hs)
```

I keep running into either a list index out of range, the sort() not working, or the temporary highscore being written 4 times.

Comment: Does the code fail with the default values of `[5000, 2000, 300]`? Also, you might want to replace your for-loop in `save` with `f.write('\n'.join[str(score) for score in hs[:3]])`. Or, since you do `hs = hs[:3]` before calling `save`, you can do just `f.write('\n'.join[str(score) for score in hs)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> list index out of range

Say your `"testscores.txt"` is empty. When `load()` is called, you get `hs = []`. Then 1 new score is inputed, you get `hs = [100]`. Then `save()` is called, and it tries to get `hs[1]` and `hs[2]` which are obviously out of range.

Instead of `open` and `close`, try to use the [`with` statement](http://cmdlinetips.com/2016/01/opening-a-file-in-python-using-with-statement/). Also don't use `global hs`, but return `hs`

```
def load():
    with open("file path", "r") as f:
        hs = f.read().splitlines()
    return hs

try:
    hs = load()
```

As for `save()`, to avoid index out of range, you want to check for the length of the input list. `hs = hs[:3]` is not necessary. Ideally, the function should be able to take care of all inputs, so let the function check this.

```
def save(hs):
    # How many scores are we saving
    # hm_score equates to 3 if more than 3 scores are in the list
    # equates to 0, 1, or 2 if less than 3 scores are in the list
    hm_score = min(len(hs), 3)

    # Trim hs to 3 if more than 3 scores are in the list
    hs = hs[:hm_score]

    with open("file path", 'w') as f:
        # Join all the scores in hs with a line break
        text = '\n'.join(hs)
        f.write(text)
    # File is closed automatically outside the with statement
```

> the sort() not working

It should be, there's nothing wrong with it. Consider putting `sort()` inside your `save()` too, to make things cleaner.

Comment: what does open(___, 'w') do?

Comment: @VandanTanna Insert the file path to ___. It opens and writes to a file, it works the same way as `open("file", 'w')` + `close()`, but cleaner. Read [this](http://cmdlinetips.com/2016/01/opening-a-file-in-python-using-with-statement/)

Comment: Thanks. I understand the 'with' statement, it was the triple underscore that I didn't get.